# Database Driver connection problems in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans-6.9

I am developing an app in Java with Netbeans 6.9.1 as the IDE. I use a MySQL database, and connect to it using JDBC.

I have a curious problem.

Class.forName() does not throw ClassNotFoundException in one package, whereas it throws it in another. What might be wrong?

JDK version is 1.6 and I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Are the two packages part of same application tier.? This problem smells of class loading issue. The two classes in question are loaded by two diff class loader.s

Comment: Are both packages part of same netbeans project? If not, check the classpath.

Comment: @doc_180 Yes, they are in the same part of the application tier. And the class that I am trying to load is MySQL driver in both the cases.

Comment: @kunal They are part of the same project, yes. But in different packages.

Comment: Could you please post a stack trace?

Comment: its kinda stupid to ask, but did you check for typos in the driver name?

Answer (score 0):

> Class.forName() does not throw
>   ClassNotFoundException in one package,
>   whereas it throws it in another. What
>   might be wrong?

The only two scenarios I can think of for this are:

1. One package is an application package and the other is a test package. In this case, you'd have to make sure Connector/J is added to the regular library list and the test library list as well.
2. They're two different projects, at which rate you'd have to add Connector/J to both projects.

Comment: No, they are both part of source packages, and they both belong to the same project. That is why I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

If you use to connect mysql with netbeans, you may have to do the steps in the following link.
----->[Netbeans Help](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html)